# How can I determine when a UITableViewCell's action buttons are shown and hidden?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitableviewrowaction

Is there a delegate method or something that I can implement that allows me to `do something` when action buttons of my tableview cell is shown and hidden again?

[image: Action buttons showing]

Comment: are you using any third party library?

Comment: @RahulPatel no. I used `-(NSArray<UITableViewRowAction *> *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` to implement the actions themselves.

Comment: may be this link will help you https://github.com/MortimerGoro/MGSwipeTableCell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tableview delegate methods:

`-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` 
and 
`-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can set some bool property at tableviewcell level, which could work like the trigger point to understand, whether the more option actions are visible or not.

You can also validate them with content offset of tableviewcell contentview, if offset < 0, it means the more option action buttons are visible, else are not visible.