# UITableViewRowAction appear/disappear event

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I've implemented `UITableViewRowAction`s successfully and now, I'd like to get events for `UITableViewRowAction` appear/disappearing in order to implement shadow of cell only when action buttons are disappeared via sliding left.
So the shadow of cell will appear only when row actions(edit, delete) are appeared and disappear when actions are disappeared.

So I guess the ideal way is to get events for appear/disappearing row actions.

Please let me know if there's any possible way to achieve this.

Comment: Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34785507/6426085

Comment: Oh,, that's what I was looking for exactly!

Comment: Great! Glad to know that helped ;)